# How many times in a row can a prime gap appear?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm wondering if there is a general answer to how many times in a row a number can appear in the prime gap sequence. For example, there cannot be three consecutive pairs of twin primes. What can be said for other gap lengths?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem?oldformat=true may help

Comment: See for example [Do certain differences of two primes occur infinitely often?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4032321). [Polignac's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture) seems to be relevant.

Comment: $(3,5)$ and $(5,7)$ are two consecutive pairs of twins primes.

Comment: @jjagmath Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For primes of the form $6m\pm 1$, the gap (called $g_n$) between a prime $p_n$ and the next prime $p_{n+1}$ must have one of three forms: $6k,\ 6k+2,\ \text{or } 6k+4$

I understand "in a row" to mean the same gap results in an arithmetic sequence of prime numbers. It is well known that in any arithmetic sequence of length $a$ that one of the members will necessarily be divisible by $a$ unless $a$ is a divisor of the first element or of the increment. Thus, for gaps of the forms $6k+2,\ \text{or } 6k+4$, since neither the starting element (a prime number) nor the increment is divisible by $3$, any arithmetic sequence of length $3$ will feature one element divisible by $3$. Hence, gaps of the form $6k+2,\ \text{or } 6k+4$ can only occur once in a row. The only exception is when the starting element is the prime $3$ itself which gives sequences such as $3,5,7$ and $3,13,23$ which have two equal gaps in a row. Note that extending such sequences by the same gap will result in the next element being divisible by $3$, i.e. not a prime number.

For gaps of the form $6k$, any five numbers in arithmetic sequence will feature a number divisible by $5$. Thus, such gaps can occur at most three times in a row, such as $7,13,19,23$. The exception here is for sequences in which the starting element is $5$ itself, which yields sequences with four gaps in a row such as $5,11,17,23,29$ or $5,17,29,41,53$. Similarly to the last case, extending such sequences by the same gap will result in the next element being divisible by $5$, i.e. not a prime number.

The maximum times the same gap can occur between successive primes of the form $6m\pm 1$ is typically three, with exceptions for sequences beginning with $5$, where four repetitions of the same gap can occur. If "in  row" is taken to mean that no prime number may be skipped over, the answer is the same (without exceptions for sequences starting at $5$), but examples are harder to find. The first I located is $251,257,263,269$

The answer by Balaji sb points to the same answer, but not with specificity.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted! Here is a follow-up observation. It also holds that the number of times a gap can occur in a row can depend on the gap that came before. For instance, a gap of length 2 can only follow a gap of length 6 if the "middle" prime is congruent to 2 mod 3. Can something more general be said about when a gap can repeat the maximum number of times?

Comment: I'm especially interested in situations when the maximum number of times a gap can occur is reduced (due to preceding gaps), but not to 0.

Comment: Except for the trivial 3,5,7 sequence, Consecutive prime-gaps cannot have the same non-zero modulus-6.  Ie,  Gaps of 2 cannot be repeated and Gaps of 4 cannot be repeated, but gaps of 6 can.  Also, a 2 cannot follow or precede an 8.  A 4 cannot follow or precede a 10. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just a property:

Let $p > 3$,
Let $p - a ,p, p + a$ be primes.

Hence, $-a \neq p \mod 3 $, $a \neq p \mod 3 $.

Since $p \mod 3 = 1  \ or \ 2$, then $a \mod 3 = 0$

So $a$ must be a multiple of $3$. But then $p + a$ is even if $a$ is an odd multiple of $3$ which is impossible.

So $a$ has to be an even multiple of $3$ i.e., a multiple of $6$.

By Similar argument, if there are $\ell + 1$ consecutive primes $p-\frac{\ell a}{2},...,p,...p+\frac{\ell a}{2}$ then $a$ has to be a multiple of all primes $\leq \ell + 1$.

So the consecutive gap number "$a$" will increase dramatically as number $\ell+1$ of primes  with same gap number "$a$" increases.

This gives a bound on $\ell$ for a given $a$. $\ell+1 \leq \max \{i: \prod_{p \leq i}p | a\}$.

So larger the number $a$, larger is the possibility of it appearing as a prime gap. But then there might be a prime inbetween $p,p+a$. So we now have,
$\ell+1 \leq \max \{i: \prod_{p \leq i}p | \ prime \ gap \}$.

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, prime gaps can repeat.  And as the formula provided shows, an arbitrary number of repeats can be chosen, which then puts requirements on the size of the gap.

Here are some highlights for the first occurrence of repeats.

```
Type,Num,Size,bounding primes.

OnlyRep,2,2,3,7
1st Rep,2,6,47,59
1st Rep,2,12,199,223
1st Rep,2,18,20183,20219
1st Rep,2,24,16763,16811
1st Rep,2,30,69593,69653
1st Rep,3,6,251,269
1st Rep,3,12,111497,111533
1st Rep,3,18,74453,74507
1st Rep,3,24,1397609,1397681
1st Rep,3,30,642427,642517
1st Rep,3,60,253444777,253444957
(four and higher requires multiple of 30)
1st Rep,4,30,9843019,9843139
1st Rep,4,60,6182296037,6182296277
1st Rep,4,90,112740413623,112740413983
1st Rep,5,30,121174811,121174961
1st Rep,5,60,293826343073,293826343373
1st Rep,5,90,8560443932347,8560443932797
```